How do I get custom linked product field items similar to Upsells to add to the cart in WooCommerce?
I need to create an additional Linked Products option in addition to Cross Sells and Up sells (Done and working... named: _upsizing_products_ids ("FBT Product" label in the admin).  Then I need to show them on the front end as Frequently bought together products.  Everything is working except I cannot figure out how to add the items from this custom field "_upsizing_products_ids" to the cart.  It is pulling Upsells, but I don't know enough to be able to get the data for my new custom field and add it to the cart with.
I have put together with other code snippets...
I can get it to pull in the data with 'post__in' => $upsizing_products_ids and the wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );, but that won't give me the checkboxes and such that I need.
// Upsizing FBT Products in additiona to cross sells and upsells under linked products

// Display the custom fields in the "Linked Products" section
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_related', 'woocom_linked_products_data_custom_field' );

// Save to custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_linked_products_data_custom_field_save' );


// Function to generate the custom fields
function woocom_linked_products_data_custom_field() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
?>
<p class="form-field">
    <label for="upsizing_products"><?php _e( 'FBT Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%;" id="upsizing_products" name="upsizing_products[]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations" data-exclude="<?php echo intval( $post->ID ); ?>">
        <?php
            $product_ids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_upsizing_products_ids', true );

            foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
                $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
                if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '"' . selected( true, true, false ) . '>' . wp_kses_post( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </select> <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Select Products Here.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
</p>

<?php
}

// Function the save the custom fields
function woocom_linked_products_data_custom_field_save( $post_id ){
    $product_field_type =  $_POST['upsizing_products'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_upsizing_products_ids', $product_field_type );
}



// add upsells to product pages as checkbox add-ons
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0 );
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form(){
    global $woocommerce, $product;

    // get the product up-sells
    $upsells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_upsizing_products_ids',true);

    if  ( (! empty($upsells)) ){

    // MAY NEED TO FILTER THESE // if ( has_term( array('core'), 'product_tag' ) && (count($upsells) > 0) ) {


    // store the number of up-sells and pass it on to the add-to-cart hook
    ?>
    <div class="hhp_product_core_cross_sells product_core_cross_sells mb-4 style-checkbox">
    <h3>Frequently Bought Together</h3>
    <div id="wb-upsell-div">
        
    <?php

    // iterate through all upsells and add an input field for each
    $i = 1;
    foreach( $upsells as $value ){
        $product_id  = $value;
        $product_obj = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            ?>
            <label for="upsell_<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-right: 20px;">

                <input id="wb-upsell-checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="upsell_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $product_obj->get_image_id(), array( 60, 60 ) ); ?>

                <?php echo( '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $product_id )) . '" target="_blank" aria-label="opens product in a new window">' . get_the_title( $product_id ) . "</a>"); ?>

                <?php echo( '<div class="fbt-price">' . "($" . get_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', true) . ")" . "</span>"); ?>
                
                <span style="margin-left: 10px;"></div>
                <input type="number" class="fbt-quantity" name="upsell_quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" min="1" value="1" max="<?php echo $product_obj->get_stock_quantity() > 0 ? $product_obj->get_stock_quantity() : ''; ?>">
                
            </label>
            <?php
            $i++;
    }
    ?>  
    </div>
</div>
    <?php
}
}

// function to add all up-sells to the cart 
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart', 10, 3);
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // get the number of up-sells to iterate through
    $upsell_size = $_POST['upsells_size'];

    // iterate through up-sell fields
    for ($i=1; $i<=$upsell_size; $i++){

        // get the product id of the up-sell
        $product_id = $_POST['upsell_' . $i];

        $found = false;

        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found )
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
}


[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/nuDQFdHP.png)
